# Jsoup: error 307 when trying to access a page

Tags: java, http, jsoup

I'm trying to access the page http://www.betbrain.com with *jsoup*,  but this give me error `307`. Anyone knows how I can fix this?

```
String sURL = "http://www.betbrain.com";
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(sURL).timeout(5000).ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).execute();
```

Comment: Change SURL to sURL. There's no string SURL, strings are case sensative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP status code `307` is not an error, it's an information saying that the server is making a temporary redirect to another page.

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for info about HTTP Status codes.

The `response` returned from your `request` holds the value for the redirect inside the headers.

To get the header-values you could something like this:

```
String[] headerValues = res.headers().values().toArray(new String[res.headers().values().size()]);
String[] headerKeys = res.headers().keySet().toArray(new String[res.headers().keySet().size()]);

for (int i = 0; i < headerValues.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + headerKeys[i] + " - value: " + headerValues[i]);
}
```

You need you own code of course for this, as you need your `response`.

Now when you look at the headers written to the console you will see a key:

`Location` which has a `value` of `http://www.betbrain.com/?attempt=1`.

This is your URL to redirect to, so you would do something like:

```
String newRedirectedUrl = res.headers("location");
Connection.Response newResponse = Jsoup.connect(newRedirectUrl).execute();
// Parse the response accordingly.
```

I am not sure why jsoup isn't following this redirect correctly, but it seems like it could have something to do with the standard Java implementation of HTTP redirects.